# Call an event handler on another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

Simple question here, but I've got a nagging feeling that there's a more interesting solution than the one I've chosen:

Page Two consists of a dropdown, and the change event is handled to execute some query.

```
protected void ddlSavedQueries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* stuff happens */
}
```

Page One is a home page, where I'm providing another version of that dropdown.  I'd like the change event in this case to redirect control to Page Two, **and** then execute the event handler.

My cheap solution is just a Redirect with a querystring value that is handled on page load.  Am I missing a more interesting approach?

Comment: Your solution about sums it up in my eyes. Or you could use a hash (#) and some tricky javascript to read it, fire a change event then let ASP take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to ugly things up with a querystring value, I suppose you could put something in `Session` and pick it up on `Page_Load` of the second page (and then clear it out of `Session`). Not exactly an awesome improvement though.

Comment: Thanks - having looked around, I'm thinking that these variations on the Redirect approach are all that's available.

Answer (score 1):

Does the same page always get displayed when you change that dropdown?  If so, consider using client side javascript to redirect to the correct page, then fire any logic on the subsequent page in the page_load event. Example using jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $("select.classyouneedtodefine").change(function() {
        document.location.href = "somepage.aspx?value=" + $(this).val();
    });

});
```

*haven't tested the above...just shooting from the hip*

Comment: Thanks - having looked around, I'm thinking that these variations on the Redirect approach are all that's available.